# Can I store name, address, and LAT/LONG from Google Places API in my own database

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Googles Places' terms about storing information can be a little confusing and I hope someone can shed some light.

I want to build a database and collect unique data on businesses but in the process my app needs to get the name and address of the business in order to store information about each business location.

I specifically want to know about storing the name, longitude, latitude, address, and possibly the place ID to build the database and speed up searches when using my database in combination with google places API. I don't want to pair my unique business data to a place ID and have to call Google Places to figure out what the name of the business is that would be a nuisance.

After building my own database I would hope to not have to use Google Places API, is this even possible with their terms or would I be stuck using them? I read that Google only has restriction on their 'Content' which excludes the coordinates because that would be public data. Is this correct and are business names and addresses public content as well?

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues (terms of use), not coding.

Comment: Last I looked at the places API terms of use, it was very clear, you aren't allowed to save **anything** persistently other than the placeId (but IANAL, nor should you act on legal advice from online forums).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant section of Maps API Terms of Service is paragraph 10.5 d which says:

> **No caching or storage.** You will not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store any Content to be used outside the Service, except that you may store limited amounts of Content solely for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation due to network latency (and not for the purpose of preventing Google from accurately tracking usage), and only if such storage:
>
> i. is temporary (and in no event more than 30 calendar days);
>
> ii. is secure;
>
> iii. does not manipulate or aggregate any part of the Content or Service; and
>
> iv. does not modify attribution in any way.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_5

Place IDs are exempt from the caching restrictions and you can save them in your database:

https://developers.google.com/places/place-id#save-id

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the accepted answer got outdated. As of now, the latest version of the [Google Maps Platform Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms) was published on **May 6, 2020**.

Point **3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services** states:

> (b) No Caching. Customer will not cache Google Maps Content except as
> expressly permitted under the Maps Service Specific Terms.

In the [Google Maps Platform Service Specific Terms](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms) you will find that not every API mention caching but the ones that do, state the same condition:

> [...] Caching. Customer can temporarily cache latitude (lat) and
> longitude (lng) values from the Geolocation API for up to 30
> consecutive calendar days, after which Customer must delete the cached
> latitude and longitude values. [...]

To sum up, you can only store the Google Place ID indefinitely and latitude and longitud for up to 30 days. [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-id) are some important details regarding Place ID and how you can use it.