# Required: (AJAX) When checkbox checked, display markers and infowindow of specific checkbox in Google maps API Biostall using CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, google-maps

I'd like to make my checkboxes work with google maps that I got from Biostall. I have so far view the google maps with markers and infowindow linked to database. My objectives now is to have the checkboxes worked, which is for example, when 'Bank' checkbox work, only Bank marker and infowindow will appear in the google maps. Another thing is that I'd like to apply it in AJAX form.

I do have an idea of how to implement it: 
$ajax
if (:checked)
show Bank marker and infowindow
else
hide

It just that I kind of confuse on how to implement it in an MVC. Below is just some of the coding that I got so far:

In View:

```
 <h6>Filter</h6>

<div class="funkyradio">
    <div class="funkyradio-default">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="bank" checked/>
        <label for="bank">Bank</label>

    </div>
    <div class="funkyradio-default">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="bookstore" checked/>
        <label for="bookstore">Bookstore</label>
    </div>
    <div class="funkyradio-default">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="electronicshop" checked/>
        <label for="electronicshop">Electronic Shop</label>
    </div>
    <div class="funkyradio-default">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="restaurant" checked/>
        <label for="restaurant">Restaurant</label>
    </div>
    <div class="funkyradio-default">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="supermarket" checked/>
        <label for="Supermarket">Supermarket</label>
    </div>
</div>

    <li><a id="list" href= "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/Main_controller3/page3" style="margin-top: 2em; background-color: Gainsboro;">List View</a></li>
  </ul><br>    
</div>

<div class="col-sm-9">
    <?php echo $map['html']; ?>
</div>
```

In Model:

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('mainpage');  
}

 public function page2(){ 
    $this->load->library('Googlemaps');

    $this->load->model('Map_model', "", TRUE);

    /*$marker = array();
    $marker['position'] = '4.943966, 114.945527';
    $marker['infowindow_content'] = 'Ideal Serusop';
    $marker['icon'] = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|9999FF|000000';
    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);*/

    //To center the main view of the map    
    $config['center']='Serusop Brunei';
    $config['zoom']="auto";
    $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

    $propertydetail=$this->Map_model->get_coordproperty();   

    foreach ($propertydetail as $detail) {

        $marker=array();
        $marker['position']=$detail->lat.','.$detail->lng;
        $marker['infowindow_content'] = $detail->property_name.'<br>'.$detail->property_address.'<br>'.$detail->property_phone.'<br>'.$detail->property_email;
        $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
    }

    $data=array();
    $data['map']=$this->googlemaps->create_map();

    $this->load->view('page2',$data);  
    }


function get_coordproperty(){
    $return=array();

    $this->db->select("property_name,property_address,property_phone,property_email,lat,lng,ptype_id");
    $this->db->from("property_detail");
    $query=$this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        foreach ($query->result() as $row){
            array_push($return,$row);
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

In Controller:

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('mainpage');  
}

 public function page2(){ 
    $this->load->library('Googlemaps');

    $this->load->model('Map_model', "", TRUE);

    //To center the main view of the map    
    $config['center']='Serusop Brunei';
    $config['zoom']="auto";
    $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

    $propertydetail=$this->Map_model->get_coordproperty();   

    foreach ($propertydetail as $detail) {

        $marker=array();
        $marker['position']=$detail->lat.','.$detail->lng;
        $marker['infowindow_content'] = $detail->property_name.'<br>'.$detail->property_address.'<br>'.$detail->property_phone.'<br>'.$detail->property_email;
        $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
    }

    $data=array();
    $data['map']=$this->googlemaps->create_map();

    $this->load->view('page2',$data);  
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would you need back end for the map? You can filter your request in the client side.

Comment: Please also be informed there are rules on what data to store when using Google Maps API please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621038/can-i-store-name-address-and-lat-long-from-google-places-api-in-my-own-databas/45676966#45676966) out